# Fancybox 2 Load Higher Resolution Images Later

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox-2

Right now I'm using Fancybox 2 to display image galleries, which is a very useful gallery tool. Right now I have it working where there's the smaller image on the page which gets clicked on to reveal a bigger, higher resolution version of the image in the gallery view, but after this I want the even higher resolution one to load after that. Is there a quick and easy way to do this, or will I have to write in my own thing to load "retina" versions of these images after the high, but not too high, versions are already displayed in the viewer?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to set the high resolution image in the `href` attribute and the highest resolution image in a (HTML5) `data-*` attribute like :

```
<a href="image01_hd.jpg" data-hd="image01_retina.jpg" class="fancybox">
    <img src="image01_thumb.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Then, using the `beforeShow` callback, we can wrap the fancybox image with an anchor with *class* `fancybox` and pointing to the highest resolution image that we can get from the `data` attribute like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            var hd = $(this.element).data("hd");
            if (hd) {
                $(".fancybox-image").wrap($("<a />", {
                    "href": hd,
                    "class": "fancybox"
                }))
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Notice** we validate if the element has a `data` attribute to avoid the highest resolution image being wrapped as well.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3rhL1wv4/)**

**Last note**: you may prefer to set the link to the highest resolution image in the `title` of the image instead of wrapping the whole thing, but at least you get the idea where to *set* and *get* the reference from within fancybox